# Right align and left align ul li elements in horizontal navigation bar

Tags: css

I am coding a horizontal navigation bar for my site.
The html is as follows:

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="special_text"><a href="#">Hello1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hello2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hello3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

The css is as follows:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

header {

}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61f231;
    border-top: 2px solid #61f231;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    border-left: 2px solid #61f231;
}

li.special_text {
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
}

li.special_text a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I would like to have some `<li>` elements aligned left while others align right.
When I try to float the ones that I want left or right there is a problem with the vertical alignment (the elements are no longer vertically aligned within the `<ul>` element.

Part of the problem arises from the fact that the first `<li>` element uses a different size font.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Its not clear to me what you mean by align left or right. By floating them left or right it seems you're trying to have 2 columns but then you talk about the vertical alignment being wrong and that makes me think you just want to just range (text-align) the li's. Perhaps you could clarify what you're required output would look like?

Answer (score 14):

All you need to do is wrap what you want in divs and `float` them `left` and `right`:

```
<nav>
        <ul><div class="floatleft">
                <li class="special_text"><a href="#">Hello1</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="floatright">
                <li><a href="#">Hello2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Hello3</a></li>
            </div>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

and add to your css:

```
.floatleft {
    float:left;
}
.floatright {
    float:right;
}
```

To fix the issue with vertical aligning, you need to mess around with `line-height` with the affected `li` elements

[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opzw3fhm/1/)

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a good solution. 
Can you explain a little bit about how you chose 30 as the value for the height and line-height properties?
I read about these properties and still don't see why these are the values that are appropriate.
Also, should I expect problems with the fact that these values are in pixels instead of percentages or relative units?
Thank you

Comment: `<div>` inside `<ul>` is not valid.

Comment: starvator....get abuse of element approach.  Although most environments will scream, it is a valid way of compartmentalizing a continuous control to their respective sides.

Comment: @MajidRahimi sometimes you have break the imposed Rules to get a simple solution implemented.  Think outside of the `display:box` and think more `display:flex`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to achieve so here are two possibilities based on my interpretation(s) of your requirements:

#### To Have Left and Right Columns:

You could use [CSS3 Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) so long as you're okay with it falling-back to a regular (non-columned) `ul` or [polyfilling](https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn) for crappy browsers (ahem <=IE9)

```css
nav ul {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
     -moz-column-count: 2;
          column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-width: 50%;
     -moz-column-width: 50%;
          column-width: 50%;
    -webkit-column-gap: 4em;
       -moz-column-gap: 4em;
            column-gap: 4em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 2</li>
        <li>item 3</li>
        <li>item 4</li>
        <li>item 5</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

See: 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn
http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

---

#### To Range The Text:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: white;
    margin: 15px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

header {

}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61f231;
    border-top: 2px solid #61f231;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 0 1.5em;
    border-left: 2px solid #61f231;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
}

li.special_text {
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Arial Black";
    text-align:left;
}
li.range_left {
    text-align:left;
}
li.range_right {
    text-align:right;
}

li.special_text a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="special_text"><a href="#">Hello1</a></li>
        <li class="range_left"><a href="#">Hello2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hello3</a></li>
        <li class="range_right"><a href="#">Hello4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Although technically correct, with parent-child nesting....way too complex for an implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If your items will not have more than one line of text you can use `line-height` to set the vertical algnment. Try this:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #61f231;
    border-top: 2px solid #61f231;
    line-height:2.5em;
}

/*Remove the padding*/
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrfne1gm/1/)**

Comment: It depends on what he means by `the elements are no longer vertically aligned within the <ul> element.` changing the line-height on the `ul` will vertically center it, changing it on the `li` will align the base of the text

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can add padding like this: `li:first-child{padding-right: 150px;}`

See my **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3523gjmu/1/)**